# What branch of mathematics is this question in a Japanese occupational aptitude test?

Tags: permutations, combinations

There is a very commonly used test called the SPI3 in Japan:  https://saisokuspi.com/

Some of the questions require combinations and permutations but I'm stuck on this practice problem.

Translated:

180 school kids were asked which vegetables they like.
100 said eggplants, 70 said green peppers, 110 said carrots.
Among the above, 40 said they like both eggplants and green peppers.
All the children liked at least one of the three choices above.
How many children only like carrots?

I know:

100-40 = 60 kids who like eggplants but don't like green peppers might like carrots.
70 - 40 = 30 kids who like green peppers but don't like eggplants might like carrots.
The 40 that answered yes to both green peppers and eggplants could also like carrots.
So 60 + 30 + 40 = 130 kids might have said yes to carrots.
But this is higher than the actual number of 110 that did.
If it was lower, then the answer would be easy to find.
110 - (number of kids who might have said yes) = num kids who like carrots only.

I have this test coming up in the next week or so.

Comment: I would call this (basic) combinatorics; specifically, this problem showcases a simple form of the [_inclusion-exclusion principle_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for counting members of sets.

Comment: I'm getting 50 students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much a permutations and combinations question, rather a set theory question. One easy way to figure this out (probably the easiest way) would be to simply draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: This was their solution as well.  100 + 70 - 40 = 130 is the size of the two circles for eggplant and green pepper leaving 50 as the size of the carrot circle minus the overlapping areas.